# Computing first and following sets (compiler design)

Tags: c, parsing

I have made this program to find out the first and following sets of the productions:

```
E->TA
A->+TA
A->0
T->FB
B->*FB
B->0
F->(E)
F->#
```

Here epsilon(NULL) is taken as 0:

```
     #include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
char a[8][8];

struct firTab
{
    int n;
    char firT[5];
};
struct folTab
{
    int n;
    char folT[5];
};
struct folTab follow[5];
struct firTab first[5];
int col;
void findFirst(char,char);
void findFollow(char,char);
void folTabOperation(char,char);
void firTabOperation(char,char);
void main()
{
    int i,j,c=0,cnt=0;
    char ip;
    char b[8]; 
    printf("\nFIRST AND FOLLOW SET \n\nenter 8 productions in format A->B+T\n");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    scanf("%s",&a[i]);  
    }
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {   c=0;
    for(j=0;j<i+1;j++)
    {
        if(a[i][0] == b[j])
        {
            c=1;    
            break;
        }    
        }
    if(c !=1)
    {
      b[cnt] = a[i][0];
      cnt++;
    }               

    }
     printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {   col=1;
    first[i].firT[0] = b[i];
    first[i].n=0;
    findFirst(b[i],i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
    col=1;
    follow[i].folT[0] = b[i];
    follow[i].n=0;
    findFollow(b[i],i);
     }

    printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<=first[i].n;j++)
    {
            if(j==0)
            {
                printf("First(%c) : {",first[i].firT[j]);
            }
            else
            {   
                printf(" %c",first[i].firT[j]);
            }
    }
    printf(" } ");
    printf("\n");
    } 
     printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<=follow[i].n;j++)
    {
            if(j==0)
            {
                printf("Follow(%c) : {",follow[i].folT[j]);
            }
            else
            {   
                printf(" %c",follow[i].folT[j]);
            }
    }
    printf(" } ");

    printf("\n");
    } 

}
void findFirst(char ip,char pos)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(ip == a[i][0])
        {
            if(isupper(a[i][3]))
            {
                findFirst(a[i][3],pos);
            }
            else
        {

        first[pos].firT[col]=a[i][3];
        first[pos].n++;
        col++;
            }
        }
    }
}
void findFollow(char ip,char row)
{   int i,j;
    if(row==0 && col==1)
    {
        follow[row].folT[col]= '$';
        col++;
        follow[row].n++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=3;j<7;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] == ip)
            {
                if(a[i][j+1] == '\0')
                {
                    if(a[i][j] != a[i][0])
                    {
                        folTabOperation(a[i][0],row);
                    }
                }
                else if(isupper(a[i][j+1]))
                {   if(a[i][j+1] != a[i][0])
                    {
                        firTabOperation(a[i][j+1],row);                                     

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    follow[row].folT[col] = a[i][j+1];  
                    col++;
                    follow[row].n++;            


                }   
            }
        }
    }   
}
void folTabOperation(char ip,char row)
{   int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(ip == follow[i].folT[0])
        {
            for(j=1;j<=follow[i].n;j++)
            {
                follow[row].folT[col] = follow[i].folT[j];
                col++;
                follow[row].n++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
void firTabOperation(char ip,char row)
{   
        int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(ip == first[i].firT[0])
        {
            for(j=1;j<=first[i].n;j++)
            {
                if(first[i].firT[j] != '0')
                {
                    follow[row].folT[col] = first[i].firT[j];
                    follow[row].n++;
                    col++;                  
                }
                else
                {
                    folTabOperation(ip,row);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

/*
input productions 

E->TA
A->+TA
A->0
T->FB
B->*FB
B->0
F->(E)
F->#
*/
```

Please review this.

Answer (score 7):

To start at the top, your two structures `firTab` and `folTab` could probably be
combined. And given a name than means something.

Your embedded constants 8 and 5 throughout should be replaced by #defined
constants to make changing them easier.

You would also do well to restructure `main` to extract parts that are are
logically complete and separate into functions.  And place `main` last to
avoid the need for prototypes.  Every other function can be static.

On compiling the code, every array subscript gives a warning: array subscript
is of type 'char'.  char subscripts are generally best avoided because char
can be signed or unsigned according to the implementation.

On the details of the code, I can't claim to have followed it through.  But
looking at the first 30 lines of `main`...

Your first action is to obtain the 8 rules you expect.  The code would be
better is it did not assume a fixed number (8) of rules or a fixed number (5)
of first/follow.

The first line of main defines some variables, but they would be better defined
at the point of first use (where possible) or one per line.  `c` and `cnt` are
not sufficiently meaningful.

You then define array `b[8]`, again with an embedded constant and an
assumption of the number of input lines.  `b` is left uninitialized and hence
will contain junk (whatever is at that stack location).

You then read the 8 input lines into `a[][]` without any checks that they fit
in the array entries.  Then follows a loop that reads through these eight
lines and puts the first character of each line into array `b` without
duplication.  There are numerous issues with these lines, the main one being
that it is such a convoluted way of doing this.  Here are some more:

- array `a` is badly named
- array `b` is badly named and is used before being initialized.  The loop
  only works by chance.
- flag `c` is badly named.  It is a boolean indicating that `b` already holds
  a particular letter.
- variables `i` and `j` should be declared as part of their loops:

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  ```
- you should add some spaces to make expressions more readable, for example
  after `if` and `for`, after `;`, around `=` and `+` etc
- your layout is inconsistent (eg placement of `c=0;` compared to other
  opening braces)

This whole loop should have been combined with the input loop so that each
time you read a new line into `a`, you checked its first character to see
whether it was in `b` and if not added it.  If we rename `b` as `letters` and
make it a nul terminated string, you can check this easily with

```
    if (!strchr(letters, line[0])) {
        // append new letter
    }
```

where `line` is the new input line.

I've only covered 50 lines of the code, but I think there is enough there for you to think about.  It looks as if you have disappeared, so I'm not sure it is worth digging any further.  If you reappear, I might :-)